# Squeaking sounds after lubricating the cogset and chain

Tags: maintenance, chain, repair, lubricant

My bicycle didn't produce any squeaks until the last weekend, when I decided to make a little maintenance. First, I used "Easy Clean" spray from the White Lightning brand to clean the cogset and the chain. Then, I applied "Epic Ride" semi-dry all conditions silicone lube from the same brand to lubricate the cogset and the chain.

When I rode my bicycle afterwards, I noticed squeaking sounds coming from the cogset. Why might this happen? Did I miss something in my maintenance procedure? Did I use wrong type of lubricant?

UPDATE
I've found some useful information from [Why is my chain so noisy after cleaning and lubricating?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/why-is-my-chain-so-noisy-after-cleaning-and-lubricating) At this point I believe that the squeaking sounds are caused by firm particles (sand) that got into the bearings or onto moveable parts in the process of degreasing. In the beginning, my suspicion was that I had used wrong type of lubricant (why they put silicone in there, anyway?). I don't think I can select the best answer from those provided below (can't upvote them either because of the low reputation), but I appreciate the effort of those who shared with me their thoughts.

Comment: Was there something more that you were looking for? Add a comment or edit the question, and we'll try to be more specific.

Comment: @zenbike, I've added an update.

Comment: Silicone wouldn't have been my first choice as a lube (even if it is sold as a chain lube).  It's not generally good at the high pressures you see in a chain.  Teflon or wax is better.

Answer (score 3):

We need more information to answer this very specifically, but the short answer is that you probably got a degreaser on a bearing area that didn't get or can't easily be re-lubricated.

Either the hub bearings in the wheel, the bottom bracket bearings, or the derailleur pulleys.

See [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/how-to-achive-an-always-clean-chain/5087#5087) for information about how to properly clean and lube your chain with out damaging anything else.

In addition, the cogset does not require external lubrication, so it is pointless to put lube on it. Lubricate the chain, and it will cover the necessary points on the cogset, externally.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any on the cogs of your rear derailleur? Might have removed some grease from them.

Next any chance it got to any internal bearings?

Those would be my first two thoughts of where to look.

Else... can you reproduce the squeaking with out the chain (e.g. take the wheel off and spin the freewheel) that might narrow it down.