# Is it possible to over-clean a bike chain?

Tags: maintenance, chain, lubricant

I've seen it [suggested](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/why-is-my-chain-so-noisy-after-cleaning-and-lubricating/1832#1832) that cleaning a chain too often or too thoroughly is bad for it, in that it removes the lubricant from the innermost parts of the chain, where it's most needed and most difficult to replace.  The [KMC website](http://www.kmcchain.eu/MAINTENANCE) in particular claims that using a bath-type chain cleaner will "instantly ruin" the chain.

On the other hand, [Sheldon's article](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/chains.html) on chain maintenance doesn't mention this at all, but suggests that fresh lube is quite capable of penetrating through to the pins and inner surfaces of the rollers.  This seems plausible to me: as long as any excess degreaser – and as much water as possible – is removed, I can't imagine any part of the chain's interior remaining unlubed.

Is there actually any evidence to suggest that "over-cleaning" is harmful to chains?  And if so, how are you supposed to extract the gunk that accumulates in the chain, which presumably can be as harmful as too little lube?

Comment: I think the context for the use of a bath type chain cleaner instantly ruining the chain is "in combination with solvent".

Comment: If and how to clean and lubricate a chain is basically a religious issue -- every source has a different viewpoint. In [this answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36873/chain-lube-that-wont-repaint-my-legs/36874#36874), I've collected the major manufacturer's recommendations. I don't think anyones got a good empirical study of chain life vs cleaning and lubrication, since riding conditions are so different. In any case, I'd guess differences would only come up to a few chains over your entire lifetime.

Comment: @Batman - I actually have some longevity data under relatively constant conditions, one test of lube and degreaser/chain cleaner gave very poor mileage (about 1/2 the longevity of just wiping clean and lubing) . Unfortunately, lube is a confounded variable so I need to rerun with a different lube to see if I still see the poor results.  But so far I am very suspicious of the impact of solvent based chain cleaners.

Comment: @Batman I realise it's contentious, but that's why I kept the scope of the question narrow and with a (hopefully) well-defined answer :-)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using a bath-type cleaner, so long as the chain is properly re-lubricated afterwards.  What is wrong is to clean a brand new chain, removing the factory wax. That wax is one of the best lubes possible.

Comment: @Rider_X I'd be interested to see the results and details, if/when you have time to write them up!

Comment: @DanielRHicks That's what I would've thought, but the KMC folks' claim about aggressive cleaning "ruining" chains surprised me.  It's a pretty strong claim – is there any merit at all in it, given their experience in the chain business?

Comment: @WillVousden - You'd be amazed at how "aggressive" some people can get.  There were once quite a few who recommended physically removing the chain (even though it didn't have a "quick link" so you'd have to "break" it), then boiling (yes boiling) in kerosene.  Their saving grace was that they'd then relube with a sort of paraffin, which is an excellent lube.  On the other hand, others now insist on "cleaning" new chains to remove the factory-applied paraffin, a dumb move.

Answer (score 4):

Evidence, not sure.  I can say I've used the Park Tool chain cleaner, which is pretty much a bath, along with Simple Green solvent for years with no problems whatsoever.

[image: park tool]

It does completely remove the chain lube/grease, which is the point.  When I clean the chain I want all the old lube off, along with the grit and dirt in the lube.

As long as you remove the solvent afterward, let the chain completely dry, and then re-lube it, on every link, carefully hitting both sides of the link, you won't have problems or shortened chain life - you should have extended chain life.

I've been using this method on a Sram 11 speed chain that's used as my daily commuter (rain, snow, city road grit) and it's like new.  The chain is 2 years old now. I should mention that I do clean it regularly and thoroughly, probably once or twice a month.

Comment: Have you checked the chain wear with a gauge? And what kind of mileage have you logged for 2 years?

Comment: By re-lubing every link, you mean re-lubing every roller, right? You should be aiming for the rides of the cylindrical rollers so capillary action can pull the lube into the bushing. One drop per roller should be plenty. Some people recommend wiping away excess lube from the chain to stop dust from forming a grinding paste.

Comment: @Batman Yes, of course I check it - it's nearly ready to change, still has some life.  I've probably put 2000-3000 miles on that bike over the last 2 years.

Comment: @Emyr Yes and no - there isn't really space to get it on the roller since they are pretty much flush with the link.  I drip it onto the outside of link from both sides and it subsequently gets sucked into the roller by capillary action like you said.

Comment: Basically you rotate the chain two or three times through the sprockets, drizzling oil onto it.  Then wipe off the excess.  If you do it right there should be a fair puddle of oil on the floor at the end.  (Protect the tire somehow when doing this -- a newspaper laid against the bottom half of the tire works pretty well.)

Comment: Or, if you have the patience, drip oil into each link seperately :] Less waste, but costs a lot more time.

Comment: Thanks.  This is more-or-less the understanding I had before I came across claims that over-cleaning is bad.  However, I do wish there were some more robust evidence out there, rather than individual anecdotes.  I see claims like those made on the KMC website about best practices (which are often propagated uncritically by other people), but it seems there's rarely any reason to believe them.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Why is it important to protect the tyre?  Just to prevent slips while riding, or is it actually bad for the rubber?

Comment: @WillVousden - First, you need to keep all lubricants off the side of the rim (assuming you have rim brakes).  Plus many lubricants are damaging to rubber.